# Scala Runtime Error : org.apache.spark.SparkException:Failed to execute user defined function(Tokenizer$$Lambda$../..: (string) => array<string>)

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, runtime-error, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-dataset

I have the following program which is running in cluster mode of 4 EMR VM

```
val spark = is a spark session
val file_path = input from args

val wherePutOutput = file_path +"\\output\\"
val whereReadingDB = file_path + "\\inputJsonFiles"
// PREPROCESS DB and WRITE IT on S3
var toBePreprocessedDB = readFullDBFromJson ( whereReadingDB, spark )  repartition 5

//PREPROCESS FULL DB
println("starting preprocessing")
val preProcessData = new DataPreprocessing ( toBePreprocessedDB )
var tokenizedPreprocessedDB = preProcessData.preProcessDF()

//WRITE PREPROCESSED DBs TO A FILE
println("finished preprocessing and starting to writing files" )
tokenizedPreprocessedDB.write mode ( SaveMode.Overwrite ) format ( "json" ) save ( wherePutOutput + "foo/" )
```

where `DataPreprocessing` class is

```
class DataPreprocessing(private var df: DataFrame ) {

  def preProcessDF(): DataFrame = {
    val cleanedDF = removePuntuaction ()
    val tokenizedDF = tokenize ( cleanedDF )
    removeStopWords ( tokenizedDF )
  }

  def setDF(newDF: DataFrame): Unit = {
    df = newDF
  }

  //return sentenceDF_clean
  private def removePuntuaction(): DataFrame = {
    df.select ( col ( "id" ), lower ( regexp_replace ( col ( "content" ), "[^a-zA-Z\\s]", "" ) ).alias ( "text" ) )
  }

  private def tokenize(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val tokenizer = new Tokenizer ().setInputCol ( "text" ).setOutputCol ( "words" )
    tokenizer.transform ( df ).select ( col ( "id" ), col ( "words" ) )
  }

  private def removeStopWords(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val remover = new StopWordsRemover ().setInputCol ( "words" ).setOutputCol ( "words_clean" )
    remover.transform ( df ).select ( col ( "id" ), col ( "words_clean" ) )
  }
}
```

Now, my runtime error is the following and it happens on the execution of the write command.

```
[ERROR] Aborting task
        org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(Tokenizer$$Lambda$2873/1370139092: (string) => array<string>)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer.$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1(Tokenizer.scala:40)
            ... 15 more
        [ERROR] Job job_20210508112210_0006 aborted.
        [ERROR] Exception in task 3.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 62)
        org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(Tokenizer$$Lambda$2873/1370139092: (string) => array<string>)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
            ... 9 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer.$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1(Tokenizer.scala:40)
            ... 15 more
        [ WARN] Lost task 3.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 62, LAPTOP-H7MM9952, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(Tokenizer$$Lambda$2873/1370139092: (string) => array<string>)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
            ... 9 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer.$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1(Tokenizer.scala:40)
            ... 15 more

[ERROR] Task 3 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
[ERROR] Aborting job f82df4a0-373c-4517-a1cf-fe70a2c7086c.
        org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 62, LAPTOP-H7MM9952, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(Tokenizer$$Lambda$2873/1370139092: (string) => array<string>)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
            ... 9 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer.$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1(Tokenizer.scala:40)
            ... 15 more
        
Driver stacktrace:
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
            at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
            at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:195)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:178)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:122)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:121)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:399)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:288)
            at ServiceMain$.block_of_code(ServiceMain.scala:105)
            at ServiceMain$.$anonfun$main$1(ServiceMain.scala:226)
            at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
            at ServiceMain$.time(ServiceMain.scala:251)
            at ServiceMain$.main(ServiceMain.scala:226)
            at ServiceMain.main(ServiceMain.scala)
        Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(Tokenizer$$Lambda$2873/1370139092: (string) => array<string>)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
            ... 9 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer.$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1(Tokenizer.scala:40)
            ... 15 more
        [ WARN] Failed to delete file or dir [C:\...\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20210508112210_0006_m_000000_59\.part-00000-15278b9c-2615-425f-a831-9622cc1e3fc2-c000.json.crc]: it still exists.
        [ERROR] Aborting task
        org.apache.spark.TaskKilledException
            at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.killTaskIfInterrupted(TaskContextImpl.scala:156)
            at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:36)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        [ WARN] Failed to delete file or dir [C:\...\output\wikidb\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20210508112210_0006_m_000000_59\part-00000-15278b9c-2615-425f-a831-9622cc1e3fc2-c000.json]: it still exists.
        [ WARN] Failed to delete file or dir [C:\...\output\wikidb\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20210508112210_0006_m_000001_60\.part-00001-15278b9c-2615-425f-a831-9622cc1e3fc2-c000.json.crc]: it still exists.
        [ WARN] Failed to delete file or dir [C:\...\output\wikidb\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20210508112210_0006_m_000001_60\part-00001-15278b9c-2615-425f-a831-9622cc1e3fc2-c000.json]: it still exists.
        [ WARN] Failed to delete file or dir [C:\...\output\wikidb\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20210508112210_0006_m_000002_61\.part-00002-15278b9c-2615-425f-a831-9622cc1e3fc2-c000.json.crc]: it still exists.
        [ WARN] Failed to delete file or dir [C:\...\output\wikidb\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20210508112210_0006_m_000002_61\part-00002-15278b9c-2615-425f-a831-9622cc1e3fc2-c000.json]: it still exists.
        [ERROR] Job job_20210508112210_0006 aborted.
        [ERROR] Aborting task
        org.apache.spark.TaskKilledException 
    ...
        [ERROR] Job job_20210508112210_0006 aborted.
        [ERROR] Aborting task
        org.apache.spark.TaskKilledException
    ... 
        Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:226)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:178)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:122)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:121)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:399)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:288)
            at ServiceMain$.block_of_code(ServiceMain.scala:105)
            at ServiceMain$.$anonfun$main$1(ServiceMain.scala:226)
            at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
            at ServiceMain$.time(ServiceMain.scala:251)
            at ServiceMain$.main(ServiceMain.scala:226)
            at ServiceMain.main(ServiceMain.scala)
        Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 62, LAPTOP-H7MM9952, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(Tokenizer$$Lambda$2873/1370139092: (string) => array<string>)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
            ... 9 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer.$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1(Tokenizer.scala:40)
            ... 15 more
        Driver stacktrace:
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
            at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
            at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:195)
            ... 27 more
        Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(Tokenizer$$Lambda$2873/1370139092: (string) => array<string>)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
            ... 9 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer.$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1(Tokenizer.scala:40)
            ... 15 more
        [ERROR] Job job_20210508112210_0006 aborted.
```

The created tokenizedPreprocessedDB is a two columns spark dataframe. <id, array(string)>

**What I already tried is:**

1. df.na.fill(...) , to remove every null value even if none was found.
2. I checked that every "WrappedArray[String]" in the column was actually a WrappedArray and not a String value.
3. I set the nullable property of the column as false

**I also noticed that,**  trying to run `"df.rdd.foreach( row => println(row))"` the execution fails with the same error. Removing "repartition by" the error is not thrown by the "println" statement, but the "write" statement throws it.

Any suggestion ?